# Grouping collection in Chaplin JS

Tags: backbone.js, collections, grouping, backbone.js-collections, chaplinjs

I need to fetch a collection of object from a server, group it by a key parameter and sum grouped value fields. Fairly simple task but I'm not sure how to achieve it in ChaplinJS.
I have set up the collection view. Fetching and rendering of ungrouped collection works fine.
How should I implement grouping and updating of collection view?

I started with groupBy, but this is not doing anything:

```
collectionView.collection.fetch().then(function() {
  collectionView.collection.groupBy(function(myItem) {
    return myItem.get('name');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am grouping a collection for a subview, I created a method for fetching grouped collection in the subview class. Same view is also responsible for showing un-grouped collection.
I fetch the collection, group it and then assign it to the view's collection for rendering.

```
var MyItemsView = CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MyItemView,
    template: template,
    tagName: 'table',
    listSelector: 'tbody',
    fetchGrouped: function(params) {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        var myItems = new MyItemCollection();
        var _this = this;
        myItems.fetch(params).then(function() {
            var grouped = myItems.groupBy(function(item) {return item.get("key");});
            var result = [];

            $.each(grouped, function(k, v) {
                var item = new MyItem();

                //Copy all attributes
                item.set(v[0].attributes);

                //Sum value field
                item.set('value', v.reduce(function(mem, value) {return mem + parseFloat(value.get('value'));}, 0));

                //Remove non-grouped values, if required
                item.unset('key2');
                item.unset('key3');

                result.push(n);
            });

            _this.collection = new MyItemCollection(result);
            dfd.resolve();
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }
});
```

I still think I am abusing Chaplin component conventions and probably there are more efficient ways to do this... But this is what I came up with.